# How do I delete a local file in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi How do I delete a local file in my application after copying it to the IsolatedStorage?

I want to delete only the file in local folder. Not in the Isolated Storage. I'm using WP 7.1.

tnks

Comment: What is the difference between wp7 and wp8 in this case? I mean what kind of problem do you have?

Comment: With IsolatedStorage there is no difference. But I want to delete the file from a folder in my app. I made a copy from from local folder to Isolated. Now I have 2 files, one local and another in IS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have write access to the folder where your application is installed. It's therefore impossible to delete the file.

Comment: Tanks KooKiz. In this case the solution is to leave the original file after the copy in local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone is designed to be one of the most secure environments in the mobile market. If you look at many of the standards it enforces you will see that this is a consistent theme.

For example:

- Your app does not have the ability to intercept calls or text
  messages (though the library exists)
- Your app cannot modify hardware buttons (there is a few MINOR
  exceptions to this rule like manipulating the back button event)
- Your app cannot access memory locations outside of the **Isolated**
  Storage it is assigned by the phone.

These standards are put in place to protect the user from malicious software and to keep a clean and consistent feel across the environment.